# Checkboxed term search

Tags: search, terms

Anyone know if I can make a checkbox-list with all terms from a taxonomy, and search for the posts belonging to the checked terms? Listing categories in the checkboxes also would be a bonus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built something similar for a client not too long ago. I believe your question is if it is possible -- I can definitely say yes there. How would you go about it? Well, as I don't have the code handy, I'll give you a brief run-down of the steps I went about.

1. I made a custom page template and created a page to use this template. In the template, I wrote an HTML form with `action=""` and `method="POST"` and set-up the checkboxes manually. You might be able to use `get_terms` to avoid having to do it manually. I made sure the `name`'s of all my checkboxes were `xxxx[]`.
2. As I wanted to handle the form in the same page (thereby setting `action=""`), I added a check for the POST variable sent by the form. If it was present, it would display the form and the search results (coming to that later). If it wasn't present, only the form would show. `if(!isset($_POST['xxxx']))`
3. In the `else`-block (the one executed if the form had been submitted) I then set-up the following arguments for the coming `WP_Query` object:

   ```
   $args['tax_query'][] = array(
   'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name_here',
   'field' => 'slug'
   'terms' => $_POST['xxxx']
   );
   ```
4. I then created the `WP_Query` object and pulled the results from it.

I hope this makes sense - I went on and AJAX-ified this along with a few other modifications, however this example shows the backbone on which I built this.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. If you wouldn't mind, could you help me on the way with some code? I´m too much of a noob to write something like this from scratch, but I´m usually able to modify something to my liking if I have something to work with.

Thanks!

Comment: Unnfortunately the code is licensed to my client, and I am unable to copy it or use it in any way. I suggest you instead try to repeat the steps I outlined and ask for clarification or further help as you go along! Also, if you feel your original question has been answered, it helps to have marked the answer as the _accepted answer_!